# Taking cell values from tr with id

Tags: jquery

I am working with AJAX and I can't read three values from 3 cells in a certain row. I need the 3rd, 4th and 7th cells

```
data: {
  status: "CLOSE",
  firstScore: $('#match' + i).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
  secondScore: $('#match' + i).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
  matchId: $('#match' + i).find('td:eq(7)').text()
},
```

Something like this doesn't work. Each row has id `#match + i`
Edit:
I read JSON from server and i try to put its values to rows to tables This all is successful.
Here is the code of adding trs and tds in trs

```
$('#matchesForClose').append('<tr id="matchh' + i + '">');
var json = array[i];
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td>" + json.date + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td>" + json.competition + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td>" + json.team1name + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td  contenteditable = true>" + json.score1 + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td  contenteditable = true>" + json.score2 + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td>" + json.team2name + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td >" + json.matchState + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td type='hidden'>" + json.matchId + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append($("<td >" + '<button class="btn btn-primary" id="submitClose' + i + '" value="Revert/Close">' + "</td>"));
$('#matchh' + i).append('</tr>');
$('#submitClose'+i).click(function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: 'closeMatch/confirm',
         data:
         {
             status: "CLOSE",
             firstScore: $('#matchh' + i).find('td:nth-of-type(3)').text(),
             secondScore: $('#matchh' + i).find('td:nth-of-type(4)').text(),
             matchId: $('#matchh' + i).find('td:nth-of-type(7)').text()
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (responseText){
              $("#closeMatches").modal('hide');
              alert(responseText);
          },
          error: function(responseText){
               alert("FATALITYYYY!");
          }
     })
});
```

Matches for close is simple table

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table" id="matchesForClose">

    </table>
</div>
```

When i click on button, status is sent, but all other data is null:
http://localhost:8081/closeMatch/confirm?status=CLOSE&firstScore=&secondScore=&matchId=

Comment: Can you show full sample? With HTML and JS. What is `i`? Does that id actually exists or you have ID as `#match+i`

Comment: What is `i`? What does the HTML look like? Do you have any errors in the console? We need a much more complete sample of your code in order to diagnose any issues.

Comment: @Justinas, edited

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that your `i` is completely different than you expecting inside click event.

Try using `$(this).closest('.class')`:

```js
// Don't put this function in loop. One binding for all buttons
$('.submit-button').click(function () {
  var table = $(this).closest('.modal-body').find('.table');
  
  alert(table.find('td').eq(1).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table" id="matchesForClose1">
      <tr><td>T1.1</td><td>T1.2</td></tr>
    </table>
    <button id="submitForClose1" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <table class="table" id="matchesForClose2">
      <tr><td>T2.1</td><td>T2.2</td></tr>
    </table>
    <button id="submitForClose2" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: And how should i move from one row to another?

Comment: @Mediumking `.next()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submitClose'+i).click(func(i));
 function func(i){
     var j = i;
     $.ajax({
         url: 'closeMatch/confirm',
         data:
             {
                 status: "CLOSE",
                 firstScore: $('#matchh' + j).find('td:nth-of-type(3)').text(),
                 secondScore: $('#matchh' + j).find('td:nth-of-type(4)').text(),
                 matchId: $('#matchh' + j).find('td:nth-of-type(7)').text()
      },
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (responseText){
                       $("#closeMatches").modal('hide');
                       alert(responseText);
      },
                 error: function(responseText){
                       alert("FATALITYYYY!");
      }`
```

I've solved it this way